# Different Template based on HTTP Referer

Tags: templates, template-redirect

He Guys,

i've been looking for a way to show a different Page-Template based on HTTP Referer or maybe the User Agent or what ever.

I'm planning an Image-Gallery which should be shown in a Fancybox. My Idea is to use a template which contains only the `loop` and all the stuff i need to build the gallery correctly (without any Header and Footer files) and load it in my Fancybox.

But what about the Search Engines und Users with disabled JavaScript. They don't see anything or only a page without the Pagecontext like Navi etc. How can i prevent this issue?

Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fancybox has built in fallback, it displays images without JavaScript.

I don't see why you would want to remove the header ( or footer) since it usually contains some good info like your doctype, css, meta, title, etc.

If you want it to look different ( aka strip it clean) you should still include it and use conditionals for your "Portfolio" page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But that is not my question... ;)

I know that doctype and meta informations are quite usefull. This is why i ask how the serve two different templates. I want to serve search-engines and users with disabled js an full-page and everybody else as an goodie the Fancybox Gallerie.

Here is an anonomized screenshot: http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3740/examplebw.png

Comment: Don't bother. Javascript support with users is about 98% and like I said it already has fallback, and who cares about search engines with regards to this is makes zero difference.